# Como fixar conteúdo à direita dentro de um navbar?

Tags: html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um site e preciso deixar um captador de leads fixado no top, junto com o menu superior, à direta do botão (como mostra na imagem).[image: Imagem ilustrativa do exemplo de menu]

```css
.lp-menu{
        min-height: 70px;
        background-image: url('http://unifacex.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/menun-fixo.png');
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .box-menu-lead{
        float: right !important;
    }
    tr > td > div.cata-lead{
        float: right !important;
    }
    .cata-lead{
        background-color: black;
        width: 340px;
        height: 540px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .box-btn-menu{
        margin: 12px 0px 12px 0px;
        float: right !important;
    }
    img.btn-menu{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
    }
    img.btn-menu:hover{
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
    .banner{
        background-image: url('http://unifacex.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/banner.png');
        width: 100%;
        height: 650px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
    div.logo > a > img{
        height: 84px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="lp-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="http://unifacex.com.br"><img src="http://unifacex.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/logo.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-btn-menu">
            <img class="btn-menu" src="http://unifacex.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/img-btn.png"/>
            <img class="btn-menu" src="http://unifacex.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/img-btn.png"/>
            <img class="btn-menu" src="http://unifacex.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/btn-email.png"/>
            <div class="cata-lead pull-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uma técnica para se fixar um elemento em relação ao seu elemento pai está demonstrada [nesta Pen](https://codepen.io/Maujor/pen/dzNdKe?editors=1100/ "Pen por Maujor"). Faço votos que você consiga adaptar ao seu caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema no final da noite desta última sexta. A solução foi semelhante ao que o Maurício postou nos comentários, com algumas diferenças. 
Eu fixei o menu ao topo desta forma
`<div class="lp-menu"></div>`

```
 .lp-menu{
    height: 84px;
    background-image: url('http://meusite.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/topo.png');
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

E depois coloquei o resto do meu código por cima, dando a devida margem ao cata-lead, ficando desta forma

```
<div class="col-md-30">
    <div class="col-md-15">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="http://unifacex.com.br">
                <img src="http://unifacex.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15">
        <img class="btn-menu" src="http://unifacex.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/btn-telefone.png">
        <img class="btn-menu" src="http://unifacex.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/btn-whats-app.png">
        <img class="btn-menu" src="http://unifacex.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/btn-email.png">
        <form class="cata-lead">
            <div class="lp-titulo">
                Preencha este formulário e garanta seu futuro entre os <obs>melhores</obs>.
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo rápido, veja se é isso e adapte como quiser, caso reste alguma dúvida só avisar.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
}

.coluna-fixa{
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  right: 10px;
  top: 55px;
}

section{
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>
<div class="coluna-fixa">
</div>
<section>
  Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.
</section>
```

Comment: É semelhante a isso, porém o box vermelho que você fez precisaria ficar alinhado à direita dos botões e como eu estou fazendo ele fica à esquerda.

Comment: No meu exemplo só você modificar o 'right'

Comment: O problema é que eu estou colocando o rigth: 0px e ele fica fixo na lateral, mas eu quero que ele fique fixo à direta no container; no tamanho máximo do container.

Comment: Ta difícil entender, e seu código não ta como você esta falando, ta realmente complicado, posta teu código atual pra eu trabalhar em cima dele.

Comment: O meu código está desta forma. Eu parei de modificar ele pois não estava conseguindo.
Deixa eu ver se consigo explicar melhor. A imagem que eu postei ilustra bem o que eu quero que aconteça. Que ele fique abaixo dos botões, que nesse caso estão como <div>, e alinhado à direita do último botão. Quando eu aumentar e diminuir a largura da página ele tem que estar sempre alinhado ao botão e não com um right fixo.